# How do I slugify the pages I pull while using the Notion API?

Tags: javascript, next.js, notion-api, slugify

I want to make a blog site on my Next.js based personal website using Notion API. I must say that I am a newbie to Next.js and Notion API. I don't have a problem pulling the posts, but I want to slugify the id's in the endpoints to replace them with the post titles. While trying to do this -by looking at a few resources-, I get a 404 error when I try to access the posts in the following state. How can I slugify the endpoint while capturing these articles?

notion.js

```js
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";

const notion = new Client({
  auth: process.env.NOTION_TOKEN,
});

export const getDatabase = async (databaseId) => {
  const response = await notion.databases.query({
    database_id: databaseId,
  });
  return response.results;
};

export const getPage = async (id) => {
  const response = await notion.pages.retrieve({ page_id: id });
  return response;
};

export const getBlocks = async (blockId) => {
  const response = await notion.blocks.children.list({
    block_id: blockId,
    page_size: 50,
  });
  return response.results;
};
```

[slug.js]

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { getDatabase, getPage, getBlocks } from "../../src/lib/notion";
import { databaseId } from "./index.js";
import { Text } from "../../src/components/text";
import Layout, { siteTitle } from "../../src/components/layout";
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";

const renderBlock = (block) => {
  const { type, id } = block;
  const value = block[type];

  switch (type) {
    case "paragraph":
      return (
        <p>
          <Text text={value.text} />
        </p>
      );
    case "heading_1":
      return (
        <h1>
          <Text text={value.text} />
        </h1>
      );
    case "heading_2":
      return (
        <h2>
          <Text text={value.text} />
        </h2>
      );
    case "heading_3":
      return (
        <h3>
          <Text text={value.text} />
        </h3>
      );
    case "bulleted_list_item":
    case "numbered_list_item":
      return (
        <li>
          <Text text={value.text} />
        </li>
      );
    case "to_do":
      return (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor={id}>
            <input type="checkbox" id={id} defaultChecked={value.checked} />{" "}
            <Text text={value.text} />
          </label>
        </div>
      );
    case "toggle":
      return (
        <details>
          <summary>
            <Text text={value.text} />
          </summary>
          {value.children?.map((block) => (
            <Fragment key={block.id}>{renderBlock(block)}</Fragment>
          ))}
        </details>
      );
    case "child_page":
      return <p>{value.title}</p>;
    case "image":
      const src =
        value.type === "external" ? value.external.url : value.file.url;
      const caption = value.caption ? value.caption[0].plain_text : "";
      return (
        <figure>
          <Image src={src} alt={caption} />
          {caption && <figcaption>{caption}</figcaption>}
        </figure>
      );
    default:
      return `❌ Unsupported block (${
        type === "unsupported" ? "unsupported by Notion API" : type
      })`;
  }
};

export default function Post({ page, blocks }) {
  if (!page || !blocks) {
    return <div />;
  }
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle}</title>
      </Head>
      <article
        className="prose dark:prose-invert dark:text-neutral-300"
        style={{ marginTop: -80 }}
      >
        <h1 className="text-4xl font-bold tracking-tighter text-stone-900 dark:text-neutral-300">
          <Text text={page.properties.Name.title} />
        </h1>
        <section>
          {blocks.map((block) => (
            <Fragment key={block.id}>{renderBlock(block)}</Fragment>
          ))}
        </section>
      </article>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const notion = new Client({
    auth: process.env.NOTION_TOKEN,
  });

  const data = await notion.blocks.children.list({
    block_id: process.env.NOTION_TABLE_ID,
  });

  const paths = [];

  data.results.forEach((result) => {
    paths.push({
      params: {
        slug: slugify(result.properties.endpoint.rich_text[0].plain_text),
      },
    });
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { slug } = context.params;
  const page = await getPage(slug);
  const blocks = await getBlocks(page.id);

  const childBlocks = await Promise.all(
    blocks
      .filter((block) => block.has_children)
      .map(async (block) => {
        return {
          id: block.id,
          children: await getBlocks(block.id),
        };
      })
  );
  const blocksWithChildren = blocks.map((block) => {
    if (block.has_children && !block[block.type].children) {
      block[block.type]["children"] = childBlocks.find(
        (x) => x.id === block.id
      )?.children;
    }
    return block;
  });

  return {
    props: {
      page,
      blocks: blocksWithChildren,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
};
```

index.js

```js
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import Layout, { siteTitle } from "../../src/components/layout";
import { Client } from "@notionhq/client";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { getDatabase } from "../../src/lib/notion";
import { Text } from "../../src/components/text";
import slugify from "slugify";

export const databaseId = process.env.NOTION_TABLE_ID;

export default function Blog({ posts }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(posts);
    posts.map((post) => {
      console.log(post);
    });
  });
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Head>
        <title>{siteTitle}</title>
      </Head>

      <section style={{ marginTop: -110 }}>
        <div className="text-stone-900 prose lg:prose-xl dark:text-neutral-400">
          <h3 className="text-3xl font-bold tracking-tighter text-stone-900 dark:text-neutral-300">
            Blog
          </h3>
        </div>
        <ol>
          {posts.map((post) => (
            <li
              className="mt-7 text-stone-900 dark:text-neutral-400"
              key={post.properties.endpoint.rich_text[0].plain_text}
            >
              <Link
                href={`/blog/${slugify(
                  post.properties.endpoint.rich_text[0].plain_text
                )}`}
              >
                <a className="text-2xl font-bold">
                  <Text text={post.properties.Name.title} />
                  <p className="text-lg font-thin">
                    {post.properties.description?.rich_text[0]?.plain_text}
                  </p>
                </a>
              </Link>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ol>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const database = await getDatabase(databaseId);
  return {
    props: {
      posts: database,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In [slug].js, you are using `const page = await getPage(slug);` while the getPage() function could only receive `id` variable.

I'm new to NextJS but here is my solution(excerpted).

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const database = await getDatabase(databaseId);
  return {
    paths: database.map((page) => ({ params: { slug: page.properties.Slug.rich_text[0].plain_text } })),
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { slug } = context.params;
  const database = await getDatabase(databaseId);
  const id = database.find((post) => post.properties.Slug.rich_text[0].plain_text === slug).id;
  const page = await getPage(id);
  const blocks = await getBlocks(id);
  return {
    props: {
      page,
      blocks: blocksWithChildren,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`value.text` -> `value.rich_text`

The reason is that the notion api has changed：
https://developers.notion.com/changelog/releasing-notion-version-2022-02-22

Comment: thanks for the advice but unfortunately that didn't solve my problem.